# Would a base64ed code work inside an images metadata?

Tags: asp.net, image, remote-code-execution

my target has a server that uses aspx possibly version 4.3 and i just found out that it has an image upload part. They have an image analyzer so it has to be an image file so i wonder if i could embed some sort of remote code execution script or webshell script written in asp and then encoded in base64

Comment: welcome - flagged as off-topic, but propose this be closed simply because there is not enough info to even engage in idle speculation;  feel free to rephrase this q to a more academic stance, and be sure to include more specific details eg. the platform in use, image formats, runtime environ, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "Could I embed a payload?" -- of course. "Would the payload get run?" -- there's no way for us to know with so little information.

Answer (score 1):

That will likely **not** work. The question of "Why not?" shall be answered with another question: "Why would it?"

---

Computers do what we tell them to do. I *highly* doubt there is any developer out there, who would write a web application, which checks if an uploaded file is a valid image in some common image format, then check for metadata and finally decode it as base64 and execute the result as shellcode.

But even in theory, this sou ds very implausible. ASP.NET applications are at their core .NET applications, which in turn are very difficult to exploit with traditional stack-based exploits.

---

In short: Merely placing executable data somewhere won't magically lead to its execution. An application has to deliberately parse that data and then decide to execute it.